# Voltage triangulation across a copper plate for touch sensing

Tags: arduino, voltage, touchscreen, arduino-uno, touch-panel

I'm using an Arduino Uno and am admittedly a bit out of my depth here. I'm trying to sense (very broadly) where on a copper plate a touch occurs. I'm using the voltage triangulation method [found here](https://github.com/aatishb/DIYtouchpad). The code and circuit are unmodified from what is in that link.

It works on a small 5x5cm piece of ITO glass I have but when I try it on my larger 35x30cm copper plate the voltage changes are equal across each contact, so I can't triangulate basically at all.

The only thing that has changed is that I've added 100 ohm resistors to both the "stylus" ground and the ground contact connected to the plate. Omitting these crashes the Arduino.

The voltage values on the ITO glass are in the 500 range, whereas the voltage values on the plate hover between 1022 and 1023, dropping to 1021 when the stylus touches the plate.

Any idea what I can do to make the triangulation a little more accurate? Even just getting drops for specific contacts instead of equal drops across all contacts would be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indium-Tin-Oxide glass is resistive (hundreds of Ohms at least); this forms a voltage divider.  That is what is detected - the difference in voltage between many points.

But a copper plate is < 0.01 Ohm.  So of course any touch is "seen" as the same place, because the plate has essentially no resistance.

Solution is to use a bigger ITO glass, or other such resistive surface.  Or research commercial 4 or 5-wire touch glass (similar principle but uses less wires.)

Comment: I'm sort of "stuck" using the copper plate - before I go out and get myself some conductive paint, do you think painting the plate would yield the desired results or would it create too much interference?

Comment: Your copper is a very tiny (in value) resistor network.
You need to increase this resistance to make any significant measurements.
Covering the plate will not do anything.

If you are using a blank PCB sheet, you could try to design some squares linked together by tiny copper traces, effectively increasing resistance.
Those tiny links would make a network of touch zones linked by resistors.
Using the smallest copper thickness may help.

Comment: @Dan - If you are really stuck using a copper plate, you are also pretty much out of luck. The problem is that your resistances are too small, producing votage differences which are too small for your Arduino to distinguish.